# can't share internet connection with virtual machine

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I've received a cloud test-server and i'm trying to test virtualization (i dont have any experience with virtualization whatsoever) ...
I have a windows server 2012 standard, and have a vm running.
However i cant share my internet connection with it.
I've created an external virtual switch, but except of losing internet connection from my server nothing happened. (vm didnt get connected to the internet).
Can anyone help me with this problem

Answer (score 0):

The solution will largely depend on the software you are using. The simplest would be to implement Network Address Translation (NAT) which will simply mirror the host connection or you can bridge straight onto the network, which is usually the best solution for a server which will require its own IP address (for example).

You can set these through the VM interface of the system you are using. Below you will find the network pages for VMware and VirtualBox, but if you aren't using one of these I am sure you can find similar documentation on the system you are using.

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)
[VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/virtual_networking_concepts.pdf)